# How do I convert Youtube Videos that download as a .webm to .mp3 in python (within the code itself)

Tags: python, download, youtube, mp3, webm

My code successfully downloads the Youtube video, but it isn't a .mp3 file and I can't find anything that explains how to convert WebM files to mp3 within the python code itself.

I realize that my approach to solving this might also be wrong, so any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

My code:

```
import pafy

url = input(str("Song URL: "))

pafy.new(url).getbestaudio().download()
```

(not sure if this matters, but I'm on windows)

Answer (score 0):

Show a list of the available formats for a specific YouTube URL which I have denoted by `<URL>` in the following line of code.

```
youtube-dl -F <URL>
```

Download the mp3 from a specific URL.

```
youtube-dl -f your-choice-of-format --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 <video URL>
```

where `your-choice-of-format` is replaced by an  format integer number that is selected from the `audio only` results of `youtube-dl -F <URL>`. The `audio only` results of `youtube-dl -F <URL>` will show a choice of available bitrates (e.g. 192k) for you to choose from, but the `video only` results of `youtube-dl -F <URL>` cannot be saved by youtube-dl to any audio format.

WebM typically uses the vorbis codec for `audio only` files, and there may be some loss of audio quality when youtube-dl converts audio from vorbis to mp3.